# Show Hidden Div Outside Another Div

Tags: html, css

I want to show hidden container outside `label`+`checkbox`. It works when I place both `div` inside the same `div`. I want it outside the `c6_top_right navtop` container, as follows:

**CSS:**

```
<style>
#setcart,span.total{cursor:pointer;}
input#setcart{display:none;}
input#setcart:checked + .remove-check{display:none;}
input#setcart:checked + #mycart{display:block;}
#mycart{display:none;position:absolute;top:50px;z-index:99999;background:#111;margin:0;padding:20px;}
.cart_content{color:#fff;}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="inner">
       <div class='c6_top_right navtop'>
          <label for='setcart'>OPEN</label><input id='setcart' type='checkbox'/>
       </div>
    
       <div id='mycart'>
           <div class='cart_content'>CLICK AGAIN TO CLOSE</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

If you find my question 'duplicate', please let me know.

Comment: This requires you to traverse UP the DOM in order to select the required element afterwards which requires a parent selector which does not exist. There are work arounds for which see the linked duplicate.